# AngularJS. ui-sref - условие, когда неопределен

Tags: angularjs

Как используя сервис ui-router, директиве `ui-sref` задать  условие, когда ссылки вообще нет?
Для обычной ссылке это можно сделать так:

```
ng-attr-href="{{true && '#/page' || undefined }}"
```

Если вместо `true` будет `false` - ссылки не будет вообще.
Как аналогично сделать для `ui-sref`?

```
ui-sref="{{true && '#/page' || undefined }}"
```

не работает

http://plnkr.co/edit/l6HvZgGeHdBeOm71Edry?p=preview

Нужно сделать чтобы при условии `false` директива `ui-sref`  в теге `<a>` не добавляла атрибут `href` этому тегу

Comment: а что происходит в случае _ui-sref_? как именно не работает?

Comment: и что значит _ссылки не будет вообще_? сам элемент _a_ уберется? или что?

Comment: Error: Invalid state ref '' .... в консоли.   в случае с ng-attr-href="{{true && '#/page' || undefined }}" атрибута href - не будет в теге <a>.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/l6HvZgGeHdBeOm71Edry?p=preview пример

Comment: поправил [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ItZq6oqRlHKHeV2nnfj?p=preview), но да проблема есть

Comment: Это забавно - но _ui-sref_ такую функцию не поддерживает, только с помощью обходных путей :-)

Comment: Обновил ответ, и добавил пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

директива `ui-sref` не позволяет сделать такое же поведение, как при использовании `ng-href`. Для обхода этого ограничения можно написать свою директиву.

```
.directive("uiSrefDisabledIf", function($compile) {
  return {
    priority: 1, //ставим приоритет, чтобы наша директива обрабатывалась раньше чем ui-sref
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {// функция выполняется один раз при сопоставлении директивы с html элементом
      //сохраняем значение атрибутов
      var uiSref = attr.uiSref,
        condition = attr.uiSrefDisabledIf;

      el.removeAttr('ui-sref-disabled-if');//удаляем с элемента нашу директиву, чтобы при вызове
      //функции ниже не попасть в бесконечный цикл
      $compile(el)(scope);

      scope.$watch(function() {//устанавливаем наблюдателя за значением. которое установлено нашей директиве
          return scope.$eval(condition)
        },
        function(conditionValue) {//если значение поменялось
          if(conditionValue){//если поменялось на true
            //убираем атрибуты, которые могут добавить href
            el.removeAttr('ui-sref');
            el.removeAttr('href'); 
          }else{//иначе
            //добавляем ui-sref с исходным значением
            el.attr('ui-sref',uiSref);
          }
          //заново связываем элемент со значениями из scope
          $compile(el)(scope);
        });
    }
  };
});
```

использовать ее можно так

```
<a ui-sref="page({page: '1'})" ui-sref-disabled-if="disabled">State 1</a>
<a ui-sref="page({page: '2'})" ui-sref-disabled-if="!disabled">State 2</a>
```

[Попробовать можно на рабочем примере](http://plnkr.co/edit/BCy25aPXRJyqMvc0NFTq?p=preview)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/l6HvZgGeHdBeOm71Edry?p=preview ui-sref в таком случае вообще не работает. Если будет true - href не будет тоже. Href должен появится от условия

Comment: @ИгорьБаранюк, вы какую-то ссылку сломанную даете - если посмотрите - там ошибки в консоли браузера

Comment: @ИгорьБаранюк, поправил [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ItZq6oqRlHKHeV2nnfj?p=preview), но да проблема есть